# Recuperar información de XML: Problema con *for each* de XSLT

Tags: xml, xsl

soy novato y me encuentro con el siguiente problema: quiero recuperar cierta información de un XML a través de una hoja de estilos XSLT. Los datos que quiero recuperar son **los nombres propios** [name] y su localización en el texto (**capítulo** [div2 @n], **folio** [pb @n], **columna** [cb @n]). Al aplicar la hoja de estilos, el *for each* del XSLT no me funciona y me pinta únicamente el primer nombre propio. 
¿Alguna idea de qué estoy haciendo mal?
Gracias!

El XML modelo que tengo es este:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<?xml-model href="http://www.tei-c.org/release/xml/tei/custom/schema/relaxng/tei_all.rng" type="application/xml" schematypens="http://relaxng.org/ns/structure/1.0"?>
<?xml-model href="http://www.tei-c.org/release/xml/tei/custom/schema/relaxng/tei_all.rng" type="application/xml"
    schematypens="http://purl.oclc.org/dsdl/schematron"?>
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="textocorto.xsl"?>
<TEI xmlns="http://www.tei-c.org/ns/1.0">
   <teiHeader>
      <fileDesc>
         <titleStmt>
            <title>Title</title>
         </titleStmt>
         <publicationStmt>
            <p>Publication Information</p>
         </publicationStmt>
         <sourceDesc>
            <p>Information about the source</p>
         </sourceDesc>
      </fileDesc>
   </teiHeader>
   <text>
      <body>
         <pb n="001r"/>
         <div1 type="book" n="01">

            <div2 type="chapter" n="000">
               <cb n="a"/>
               <head> Capítulo 1 </head>
               <ab> Este es el texto del capítulo 1 de la columna A del folio 1r y le pongo dos
                  nombrecitos <name>Don alfonsso</name> y otro nombrecillo para no perdernos doña
                     <name>beatriz</name>
               </ab>
            </div2>
            <div2>
               <cb n="b"/>
               <head>Capítulo II </head>

               <ab>Este es el texto del capítulo II, que se encuentra en la columba B del folio 1r.
                  Y vamos a poner unos nombres: don <name>alfonso</name>, doña <name>Urraca</name>
               </ab>
            </div2>
            <pb n="001v"/>
            <div2>
               <head>Capítulo III</head>
               <ab> Este es el texto del capítulo 3. Vamos a poner tres nombres:
                     <name>Fernando</name>, <name>Leticia</name> e <name>Isa</name>
               </ab>
            </div2>

         </div1>
     </body>
   </text>
</TEI>
```

La hoja de estilos que estoy aplicando es la siguiente:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0"
    xmlns:tei="http://www.tei-c.org/ns/1.0">
    <xsl:output method="html"/>
    <xsl:template match="/">
        <html lang="es">
            <head>
                <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8"/>

            </head>
            <body>
                <h1>Nombres propios</h1>
                <xsl:for-each select="tei:TEI//tei:name">
                    <p/>
                    <xsl:apply-templates select="/tei:TEI/tei:text/tei:body/tei:pb"/>,
                    <xsl:apply-templates select="/tei:TEI/tei:text/tei:body/tei:div1/tei:div2/tei:cb"/>
                    <xsl:apply-templates select="/tei:TEI/tei:text/tei:body/tei:div1/tei:div2"/>

                </xsl:for-each>
            </body>

        </html>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="/tei:TEI/tei:text/tei:body/tei:pb">
        <xsl:for-each select="/tei:TEI/tei:text/tei:body/tei:div1/tei:div2/tei:ab/tei:name"/>
        <xsl:value-of select="@n"/>: <xsl:value-of
            select="/tei:TEI/tei:text/tei:body/tei:div1/tei:div2/tei:ab/tei:name"/>

    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="/tei:TEI/tei:text/tei:body/tei:div1/tei:div2/tei:cb">
        <xsl:for-each select="/tei:TEI/tei:text/tei:body/tei:div1/tei:div2/tei:ab/tei:name"/>
        <xsl:value-of select="@n"/>


    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="/tei:TEI/tei:text/tei:body/tei:div1/tei:div2">
        <xsl:for-each select="/tei:TEI/tei:text//tei:div1/tei:div2/tei:ab/tei:name"/>
        <xsl:value-of select="@n"/>
    </xsl:template>  
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Los capítulos y nombres puedes obtenerlos así:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0"
    xmlns:tei="http://www.tei-c.org/ns/1.0">
    <xsl:output method="html"/>
    <xsl:template match="/">
        <html lang="es">
            <head>
                <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8"/>
            </head>
            <body>
            <xsl:for-each select="//tei:div1/tei:div2">
                <h1>Capitulo <xsl:value-of select="[@n]" /></h1>
                <h2>Nombres propios</h2>
                    <xsl:for-each select=".//tei:name">
                        <p><xsl:value-of select="." /></p>
                    </xsl:for-each>
            </xsl:for-each>
            </body>
        </html>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Para el Xml que aparece en tu pregunta, genera:

> ## Capitulo 000
>
> ### Nombres propios
>
> Don alfonsso
>
> beatriz
>
> ## Capitulo
>
> ### Nombres propios
>
> alfonso
>
> Urraca
>
> ## Capitulo
>
> ### Nombres propios
>
> Fernando
>
> Leticia
>
> Isa

Faltaría agregar folio y columna. El problema con la template que estabas usando es que por cada elemento empieza a extraer todo desde el raíz, no desde la ubicación actual.